# Redirect console output to message with python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I've created a class with an add method. It saves the names of different tokens in a `.txt` file, only if they aren't there in the first place. If the `.txt` file doesn't exist, it informs the user and creates the file. It looks something like this:

```
class watchlist:
    def __init__(self, tokens=[]): 
        self.tokens = tokens
    
    def add(self, new_tokens):
        # Check if user has a watchlist, eliminate repeated tokens
        try:
            with open ("watchlist.txt", "r") as registry:
                for line in registry: 
                    existent_token = line.strip('\n')
                    if existent_token in new_tokens:
                        new_tokens.remove(existent_token)
                        print(f"{existent_token} was already on your watchlist")
        except FileNotFoundError: print("This user has no watchlist. A new watchlist will be created")
        
        # Add new tokens to watchlist
        with open ("watchlist.txt", "a") as registry:
            for new_token in new_tokens:
                registry.write(f'{new_token.upper()}\n')
                print(f'{new_token} added to portfolio')
```

Thing is, instead of printing the comments to the terminal, I want to send them as messages, without sending them from within the class. I don't want to replace the line:

```
print("This user has no watchlist. A new watchlist will be created")
```

with

```
context.bot.send_message(chat_id=user.effective_chat.id, text="This user has no...")
```

because I want to keep the classes in a separate file. What's the proper way of redirecting that output so that the main function can send the messages while the method is running?

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize your watchlist class with an object having a write function. Setting the object to `sys.stdout` will print to the terminal, setting it to a custom writer will direct the output somewhere else, for example:

```
import sys

class customOutput:
    def write(self, msg : str):
        # TODO: send via telegram
        print("Custom output - Msg: " + msg)

    
class watchlist:
    def __init__(self, writer) -> None:
        self._writer = writer

    def add(self):
        self._writer.write("Some message")

my_watchlist = watchlist(customOutput())

my_watchlist.add()

my_watchlist = watchlist(sys.stdout)

my_watchlist.add()
```

prints:

```
Custom output - Msg: Some message
Some message
```

Comment: But doesn't that mean I have to keep the definition of `customOutput` in the same file as `watchlist`, thus having to implement `send_via_telegram()` there? I don't see how I could use that class without importing the bot into the file

Comment: The definition of your writer can also be in another file or module, only when you create your watchlist, you need the writer class. If you are on how importing in python works, you could also have a look here: https://realpython.com/python-import/

Answer (score 0):

I guess the main point here is that you don't necessarily need the `context` argument of a handler callback to send messages - all you need is an instance of `telegram.Bot`. In the `main` this is usually available as `updater.bot` or `dispatcher.bot` and you can use it there to initialize  your setup. In the solution suggested by [Roman Purgstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70500820/10606962), you could create an instance of `customOutput` in the `main` and initialize it by passing `updater.bot` to it.